# Uploading Storing an Image inside a MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysqli

i am trying to Upload and Store an Image inside a MySQL, for some reason i got a broken photo when photo is submitted . i think there is a problem with $image = $image->fetch_object(); also when i click on the broken photo i get the following error message: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object any suggestion how to fix this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Upload an Image</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            File: 
            <input type="file" name='image'/> <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>

        <?php
        //connect to database
        try{
            $db = new mysqli('','','','');

        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
            $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];//['tmp_name'] is the temporary location 
        }

        if(!isset($file)){
            echo 'please select an image';
        }else{
            $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
            $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);


            if($image_size == false){
                echo 'thats not an image';
            }else{

                $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO store VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
                $insert->bind_param('bsi', $image, $image_name, $image_size);
                if(!$insert->execute()){
                    echo "Problem uploading file";
                    }else{
                    printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $insert->affected_rows);
                    echo $lastid = $db->insert_id;//returns the last id that was inserted 
                    echo 'image uploaded.<p/> Your Image:<p/><img src=get.php?id=$lastid>';
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is the updated code, i dont get an error anymore but image is still broken 
    getMessage();
    }

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];//request because we going to use it inside an image tag

$image = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM store WHERE id=?");
$image->bind_param('s',$id);
if($image->execute()){    
    $image = $image->fetch();
}

$image = $image->image;
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

echo $image;

?>
```

Comment: The problem is in HTML, which you have to learn first

Comment: Isn't it bad practice to store images in mysql? If I HAD to do that, I'd store the data uri of the image in the database, not the data from file_get_contents.

Comment: i know its bad but i am just testing @WackyWalrus

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I missed the main point.

The following code can't work:

> ```
> $image = $db->query('SELECT * FROM store WHERE id=$id');
> $image = $image->fetch_object();
> ```

$id in the first statement will not evaluated, because it's a string in single quotes.

The cause for broken images may be the use of addslashes() to mask the input, which is binary data. I would use a prepared statement with parameters and bind the input data .

---

Old answer

The PHP-manual says (http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> Files will, by default be stored in the server's default temporary
>   directory, unless another location has been given with the
>   upload_tmp_dir directive in php.ini.
>
> [...]
>
> Whatever the logic, you should either delete the file from the
>   temporary directory or move it elsewhere.
>
> [...]

You should move the uploaded file with [move_uploaded_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), before you're working with it. And I won't advocate the storing of images in databases too ...

Comment: I completely approve of this, but he said he's testing how he would save an image in a database. Personally, I always move the file to somewhere on the server. No need to have all that image data in the DB.

Comment: i updated the code with prepared statement with parameters and bind the input data, now i dont get error but still a broken image

Comment: @KarishKarish You should be able to use the same binding mechanism for the saving part of your script. But that's not all. You've got to check the type of image after upload, so you can set the right header, if the image is requested. Those images aren't ever jpegs.

Comment: @VMai  currently i am uploading jpeg file so it shouldn't be the problem, also what do you mean by saving the script

Comment: @KarishKarish You've used [addslashes()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) to escape your binary data. As I said, that may not be enough. Please rewrite the saving part so it uses the bind mechanism too. It ensures you get exactly the original data from your image in your database. Broken data cannot be easily fixed. Better throw away all broken images.

Comment: @VMai i updated the code using the bind mechanism  still get broken image any suggestion

Comment: @KarishKarish If your current code with base64_encode() you've got to decode it before sending it to the browser. With your method there's no need to base64_encode() the image.

Answer (score 1):

Your save script:

```
 if(!$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']){
     $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
     $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
     $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
     if(!$insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO store (name,image) VALUES('{$image_name}','{$image}')")){
         echo "Problem uploading file";
     }else{
         echo $lastid = $db->insert_id;//returns the last id that was inserted 
         echo 'image uploaded.<p/> Your Image:<p/><img src='data:image/png;base64,<?=$image;?>';
     }
 }
```

That way when you need the image you can just grab the data uri from the database and re-use it.